# jQuery loop through JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json array which i fetch by a ajax call and would like to loop through it.
The array outputs a category titel and some data records within that category.
The array is as followed:

```
{"Travel":[{"title":"Beautiful title 1"},{"title":"Beautiful title 2"},{"title":"Beautiful title 3"}],"Other":[{"title":"Beautiful title 1"}]}
```

The basic each function like so can't help me.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value.title);
}
```

I want to be able to output it with the main category title and under that have the data records shown.

So for example i want it to look like this:

Travel (3 results):

- Beautiful title 1
- Beautiful title 2
- Beautiful title 3
- List item

Other (1 results):

- Beautiful title 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: isnt it an object and not an array? or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
var data = {"Travel":[{"title":"Beautiful title 1"},{"title":"Beautiful title 2"},{"title":"Beautiful title 3"}],"Other":[{"title":"Beautiful title 1"}]};

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
  $('body').append($('<div></div>').html(key + ' (' + value.length + ' results)'));
  var list = $('<ul></ul>');
  $('body').append(list);
  $.each(value, function (index, titleObj) {
    list.append('<li>' + titleObj.title + '</li>');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, changed the code a bit to fit my needs. I've marked your answer as correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $("<ul />", {
    "class": key.toLowerCase(),
    "html": key + " (" + value.length + " results)<br />"
  }).append($.map(value, function(title, i) {
    return $("<li />", {
      "html": Object.keys(title)[0] + ":" + title.title
    })[0].outerHTML
  })).appendTo("body");
});
```

```js
var data = {
  "Travel": [{
    "title": "Beautiful title 1"
  }, {
    "title": "Beautiful title 2"
  }, {
    "title": "Beautiful title 3"
  }],
  "Other": [{
    "title": "Beautiful title 1"
  }] 
};

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $("<ul />", {
    "class": key.toLowerCase(),
    "html": key + " (" + value.length + " results)<br />"
  }).append($.map(value, function(title, i) {
    return $("<li />", {
      "html": Object.keys(title)[0] + ":" + title.title
    })[0].outerHTML
  })).appendTo("body");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need nested `.each()` as the array contains nested objects.

```
$.each(data,function(i,object){
    console.log(i +'('+object.length+')')
    $.each(object, function (index, obj) {
        console.log(obj.title);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v97e5sh8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a Travel key their

So you can do it like :

```
$.each(data.Travel,function(key, value){
    console.log(value.title);
}
```

Comment: I can't because the category titles are pulled from database, there could be 300 different categories, so i would never know all the titles otherwise i would have already done that.